# How to mix in traits with implicit vals of the same name but different types?

Tags: scala, traits

I have traits from two third party libraries that I'm trying to mix in to my own trait. They both define `implicit val`s named `log`.

However, they are of different types - one is an SLF4J `Logger`, the other is a Spray `LoggingContext` (which is really an Akka `LoggingAdapter`).  In fact the second trait is from Spray, it's an `HttpServer`.  (Not the most recent version you can find on Github which no longer has that `val`).

So, here's the code (library one renamed because it's proprietary, the Spray code snipped to show just relevant part):

```scala
object LibraryOneShim {
    trait LibraryOne {
        implicit val log: org.slf4j.Logger = ...
    }
}

// https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/a996a5b6bdd830e613583fed86e87bf049fdb8c0/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/HttpService.scala
trait HttpService extends Directives {
    val log = LoggingContext.fromActorRefFactory // this is a LoggingContext/LoggingAdapter
}

trait MyTrait extends HttpService with LibraryOne {
    val myRoute = ...
}

class MyActor extends Actor with MyTrait {
    def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}
```

This won't compile.  The compiler complains:

> error: overriding lazy value log in trait HttpService of type
>   java.lang.Object with spray.util.LoggingContext; lazy value log in
>   trait LibraryOne$class of type org.slf4j.Logger needs `override'
>   modifier trait DemoService extends HttpService with LibraryOne {

Is there any way I can mix in these two traits together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only way is to create a `CombinedLogger`

```
class CombinedLogger(l1:Logger, l2:LoggingAdapter) extends Logger with LoggingAdapter {
   // proxy methods to the correct logger
}
```

If both loggers were declared as `def` you could use it like this:

```
override def log = new CombinedLogger(super[LibraryOne].log, super[HttpService].log)
```

In this case it's tricky because they are defined as `val` which tell the Scala compiler they are a single value that will not change. And because of that it will not allow you to call `super.log`. So you would need to copy the logic of the overridden traits.

The other tricky part in this case is that you would need to proxy 50+ methods in the `CombinedLogger`.

Comment: I see. Yeah, that would probably work but... ick.  I'm glad it's a moot point.  Moral of the story, don't put vals with commonly-used names like "log" in your library...

Comment: And if you do, at least declare them with `def`